# Customize the \columnseprule for one particular column in \multicols environment

Tags: multicol, rules, columns

I'm trying to do a poster presenting what the starting point of my thesis is about. For this, I'm using a `\multicols` environment composed of three columns.

The problem is that I want a particular block to span over 2 columns. I easily achieved that using a `minipage` environment, but the `\columnseprule` passes over the text contained in my `minipage`, resulting in a very, very ugly output.

I've tried to google it, and searched here on stackexchange, but the only thing I found was able to modify all of the `\columnseprules`, and not only a particular one, what also resulted in a pretty ugly output.

Here's a MWE. You will also need the `a0poster` and `widetext` files to be able to compile. Links to the files are provided at the end of the post.

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0b,final]{a0poster}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{widetext}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Columns spacing and separation
\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}

%Poster environment
\newenvironment{poster}{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.90\textwidth}
}{
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}

%Pbox
\newcommand{\pbox}[4]{
\psshadowbox[#3]{
\begin{minipage}[t][#2][t]{#1}
#4
\end{minipage}
}}

%Title box
\newrgbcolor{lblue}{0.8 0.92 0.95}
\newcommand{\titlebox}[1]{\begin{center}\pbox{0.6\columnwidth}{}{linewidth=2mm,framearc=0.1,linecolor=blue,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradbegin=white,gradend=lblue,gradmidpoint=1.0,framesep=1em}{\begin{center}\LARGE #1\end{center}}\end{center}\vspace{1.5cm}}


\begin{document}
\begin{poster}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    TITLE      %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\titlebox{\textbf{\huge Some title}}

\vspace*{1cm}

\textsl{\LARGE Author1, Author2, Author3}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \large
    \center
    Location \\
    And \\
    Contact \\
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\vspace*{3cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    CONTENT    %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{multicols}{3}

%COLUMN 1
\titlebox{Intro}

\lipsum[1]

\vspace*{2cm}

\titlebox{State of the art}

\lipsum[1-6]


\newpage


%BLOCK I WANT TO SPAN 2 COLUMNS
\begin{minipage}{2\columnwidth}

\titlebox{Problem we're gonna study}

\lipsum[1]

\end{minipage}


\vspace*{2cm}


%COLUMN 2
\titlebox{Existing solution (not good enough)}

\lipsum[1-7]


\newpage


%COLUMN 3
\vspace*{14cm}
\titlebox{Our solution (better than the previous one (we hope))}

\lipsum[1-6] 

\end{multicols}
\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

And here is the ouput problem:

[image: Output problem]

I'd like the separating line to start just at the level of the two titles at the bottom.

Any solution would be appreciated, as long as I can keep my `\multicols` environment (maybe I'm asking a lot? I don't know), otherwhise I'll just get rid of the separation lines, even if it looks a bit worse.

Thanks in advance.

Link for widetext : https://svn.einsteintoolkit.org/documents/Paper_EinsteinToolkit_2010/widetext.sty

Link for a0poster : www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~marchini/software/a0.LaTeX.posters/a0poster/a0poster.sty

Sorry I can't post "real" links, but I don't have enough reputation to post 2 links at once.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to achieve what I wanted with the use of a `pspicture` inside `\SetBgContent` to draw the separation lines. Maybe not the best solution, but it works and looks good now.